# Importar un documento excel a mysql mediante php

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpexcel

Estoy mirando la manera de subir un archivo *CSV* y también *xlsx* a una base de de datos **MySQL** desde **PHP**. Ya he investigado por **Google** y he tomado los ejemplos que dan pero no me funcionan.

Lo que pasa es que estoy encargado del formulario de varios menús, donde con un radio escogen y dan *click* sobre consultar y trae la información referente. Cada radio tiene un case dónde se realiza la consulta y la muestra, pero aparte de eso, en una de ellas necesito importar masivamente los campos de la tabla mostrados. Ya lo he hecho directamente en el case, no me importa nada, con require tampoco... No sé cómo hacerle más.

Espero haber sido acertado y hacerme entender... Gracias.

Comment: necesitas subir en csv y xml, es decir quieres poder leer estos dos tipos de formato en php?

Comment: No. En el case tengo una consulta que me trae los datos al formulario en una tabla. Necesito la opción de importar a la base de datos varios registros. Intenté que dentro de ese mismo case estuviera la importación con una consulta distinta pero creo que no es posible

Comment: Te hago la pregunta ya que si se trata de subir y leer un archivo CSV para despues hacer las inserciones en na base de datos te puedo ayudar en eso

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, de una manera muy fácil. Linkee un nuevo formulario dedicado solo para la subida del archivo masivo. Gracias por tratar de colaborar.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que quieres subir archivos **CSV** y **XLSX** a tu base de datos.

Primero debes procesar el excel para convertirlo en **CSV** y así poder subirlos.
Deberías mostrar la pantalla o código de tu formulario de carga, pues no me queda claro cómo quieres realizar la carga.

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, de una manera muy fácil. Linkee un nuevo formulario dedicado solo para la subida del archivo masivo. Gracias por tratar de colaborar.